# Using jquery how do I pass a url query string to another php file?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to pass the selected value of a autocomplete combobox uisng jquery-ui, now what I want to do is on the selection change event of the combobox I want to pass the selected value to a query string so that I could have a php file that will have something like this $_SESSION['mysession'] = $_GET['TheValue'];

Here's my current code:

```
                        change: function( event, ui ) {

//$.get('save_session_var.php', {supplier_id: $(this).val});


//document.location.href("localhost:90/PurchaseOrder3/save_session_var.php");
//alert($("#combobox").attr("value"));


if($("#combobox").attr("value") !== "")
{
    $("#SupplierId").val($("#combobox").attr("value"));
    alert($("#combobox").attr("value"));
    $("#items").empty();
    $("#items").append('<a id="AddLink" href="#">Add Item</a>');
    if(!$("#items").has('a #AddLink'))
    {
    $("#items").append('<a id="AddLink" href="#">Add Item</a>');
    }
}



<body>

    <form method="post">
            <p>Choose Supplier:<select name="SupplierDDL" id="combobox">

            <option value=""></option>

            <?php include 'loadSuppliers.php'; ?>
        </select><p> 
        <input name="" type="hidden" value="" id="SupplierId">

               <div id="items"><p>asdasd</p></div>
               <input name="id" type="submit">
            </form>
```

I tried using the ff but it didn't work:

```
$.get('save_session_var.php', {supplier_id: $(this).val});
$.get('save_session_var.php', {supplier_id: $("#combobox").attr("value"));
```

Here's also my code for the php file I created  'save_session_var.php':

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['supplier_id'] = $_GET['supplier_id'];
```

I've been stuck with this problem for almost the whole day. My only goal is just to be able pass the selected value and create a session variable.

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help and be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your javascript code down to what's relevent.  TL:DR

Answer (score 1):

Use `ui.item.option` to get the underlying `<option>` element.

```
$.get('save_session_var.php', {
  supplier_id: ui.item.option.value
});
```

Or use `ui.item.value` to get the selected option's text.

Comment: It didn't work but thank you++ anyway for at least providing a possible solution and ui.item.option.value was better way getting the IDs. but it still didn't work I tried echo the session but it said that it's undefined index.

Comment: @randelramirez1, What is the output of a `var_dump($_GET)` at server side?

Comment: sorry sir for the late reply. There's no value I did not set var_dump($_GET).

Comment: it's weird because when I do $a = "hello";
$.get("save_session_var.php", { name: $a, time: "2pm" } ) I'm able to store the session with a value of hello I also changed GET['name']. But when I try to get the value of the selected item it returns undefined index.

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

Edit: this works for me.

```
var yourVar = "I saved it again!";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "save_session_var.php",
    data: 'suplier_id=' + yourVar,
    cache: false,
    success: function(text){
        alert(text);    
    }
});
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = $_REQUEST['suplier_id'];

echo "THIS IS WHAT YOU GET: " . $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Comment: It didn't work but thank you++ anyway for at least providing a possible solution

Comment: It should save.  But if you just echo out the change in the PHP file, you need to grab that output with the "success:" ajax option to do something with it right away.

Comment: it's weird because when I do $a = "hello";
$.get("save_session_var.php", { name: $a, time: "2pm" } ) I'm able to store the session with a value of hello I also changed GET['name']. But when I try to get the value of the selected item it returns undefined index.

Comment: are you trying to use the PHP $a variable? or are you using a javascript variable in the $.get() ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using the following code:

```
var selectedId = $("#combobox").val().toString();
$.get("save_session_var.php", {supplier: selectedId} )
```